# change div parent and arrange after drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please anyone can help me with these div s. I need to move them from a column to another using drag and drop. Actually they are dragged and dropped but i need to arrange them correctly in selected columns.

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .header {
        background-color: #C0C0C0;
        height:70px;
        width:1308px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        ;
    }
    .columns {
        background: #C1C1C1;
        height:400px;
        width: 1308px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px
    }
    .col {
        background: #C1C1C1;
        float:left;
        height:400px;
        width: 325px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .box {
        background: #F0F0F0;
        cursor: move;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:10px;
        height:100px;
        width: 200px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
    }
    #box1 {
        background: #F0F0F0;
        cursor: move;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:10px;
        height:100px;
        width: 200px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #box1.moveable {
        background:#333;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
    #box2 {
        background: #F0F0F0;
        cursor: move;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:10px;
        height:100px;
        width: 200px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #box2.moveable {
        background:#333;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
    #box3 {
        background: #F0F0F0;
        cursor: move;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:10px;
        height:100px;
        width: 200px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #box3.moveable {
        background:#333;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
    #box4 {
        background: #F0F0F0;
        cursor: move;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:10px;
        height:100px;
        width: 200px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    #box4.moveable {
        background:#333;
        border: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script>
    function startMove() {
        $(".movable").on("mousemove", function(event) {
            var thisX = event.pageX - $(this).width() / 2,
                thisY = event.pageY - $(this).height() / 2;

            $(".movable").offset({
                left: thisX,
                top: thisY
            });
            $(this.parent()).detach().css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).appendChild();
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#box1").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).addClass("movable");
            startMove();
        }).on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("movable");

            console.log($(this).attr('id'));




        });
        $("#box2").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).addClass("movable");
            startMove();
        }).on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("movable");

            console.log($(this).attr('id'));

        });
        $("#box3").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).addClass("movable");
            startMove();
        }).on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("movable");

            console.log($(this).attr('id'));

        });
        $("#box4").on("mousedown", function() {
            $(this).addClass("movable");
            startMove();
        }).on("mouseup", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("movable");

            console.log($(this).attr('id'));

        });
    });;
</script>
    </head>

<body>
<div class="header">
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">header</p>
</div>
<div class="columns">
    <div class="col" id="column1">
        <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
        <div class="box" id="box2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="column2">
        <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" id="column3"></div>
    <div class="col" id="column4">
        <div class="box" id="box4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LenYB/

Comment: your code is working ,so what is your problem?What output you want?

Comment: why reinvent the wheel - http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ and https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: is working but when i move boxes , they can be overlapped. And when i drag a box into another column, i need the box to be fixed, like a sorting list of boxes. @PratikJoshi

Comment: on the right side ,there ,it doesnt allow more than one Box,what is this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LenYB/3/ @PratikJoshi this is the correct demo. sorry

Comment: what are you saying,speaking? If you dont have any problem ,have correct code, why to waste our time

Comment: is working but when i move boxes , they can be overlapped. And when i drag a box into another column, i need the box to be fixed, like a sorting list of boxes.@PratikJoshi